# Error Validation failed When Create SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure and learning it. An error returned when I am trying to create SQL database in Azure.

[image]

```
{
  "code": "InvalidDeploymentParameterValue",
  "message": "The value of deployment parameter 'digestRegion' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference. See https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for details."
}
```

I am using an Azure free account and I checked the free account limit, it shows that 250 GB of Azure SQL Database standard S0 instance with 10 database transaction units is allowed.

I also tried to change the Sqlserver region to west, central, west2,west3, but the same error occurred.

When I checked the deployment template and search for "Region", the 'digestRegion' parameter is actually empty. I guess it should be the region name. Where should I find the applicable options?

[image]

I searched online for the error but had no luck. Thank you for any suggestions.

**UPDATE：**
I also posted this problem in the MS Azure Community and the problem would be solved by MS at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, The deployment for the fix is in progress and will be completed in couple of hours from now.